Manage multiple environments on same VM
For a internal test & integration environment (prod is isolated of course) I tried to manage multiple base path :

("/env1" + "/env1/assets) + "/env1/api"
("/env2" + "/env2/assets) + "/env2/api"
("/env3" + "/env3/assets) + "/env3/api"

For that I have a VM with docker. To be simple I have one container for each instances of back and front and one for nginx with port mapping.
My nginx routing seems to works but I have one last problem :
When I build my different environments' images for the Angular front, even by changing --base-href, that did not change the base url of main, polyfills, lazy-loaded chunks and assets (css, favicon, ...) in the index.html files (e.g. still <link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-LYLLMOEK.js"> instead of <link rel="modulepreload" href="<my_defined_base_href>/chunk-LYLLMOEK.js">).
I don't know if I give enough informations but it could be great if someone have an idea for that.
If you have some answers I'll take it gracefully.
Thanks in advance peoples ! :)
Here is a (really) simplified schema of my goal :
enter image description here

After some searches I found that "publicPath" was the way to manage that on older Angular versions but it's deprecated (I'm in Angular 17).
I thought also to change the webpack config but I did not find clear examples or documentation.
I see some workarounds that directly replace url string in index.html file but I don't find it really clean.

